# How do I reference only the elements of a multi-column range that meet particular conditions?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet made up of several individual sheets: one sheet for each category of product and one sheet designed to be a "global view." In each sheet is a 3-column range of variable length with the headings "Name", "Status", "Material type". These ranges are named so that I can refer to them easily. Something like this:

```
Rangename = "Portnoy"

       [D]         [E]              [F]
[1]    **Name**    **Status**        **Material Type**
[2]    Portnoy     Pending           Other 
[3]    Sinclair    Complete          Case
[4]    Jeffries    Pending           Other
[5]    Davis       Complete          Case
```

On another sheet, I would like to mirror only those cells under the headings `**Name**` and `**Status**` whose material type is `case`. I can sort of make this work using `VLOOKUP`, but I've only gotten so far as making it work for one individual cell; I can't make it so both the name and status appear in adjacent cells, and I definitely can't get it to spit out the entire range. Ideally results would look like this, generated with one function:

```
Sinclair    Pending
Davis       Complete
```

The goal is to have a global view whose statuses will update dynamically. I know that `ARRAYFUNCTION` has a role to play here, but I'm stymied. All suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Can you share a doc with us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly the job of the [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) command:

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!D:F, "select D,E where F='Case'")
```

returns

```
Sinclair    Complete
Davis       Complete
```